# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed in framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net, oracle, web-config, dataprovider, .net-framework-version

I have developed a web application in Framework 4.0. Now I am implementing the bundling concept, which Framework 4.5 supports in existing applications. Before I deploy the application, I've installed Framework 4.5 in my local QC environment because bundling is working only when we installed framework 4.5.
But now I can't access my application due to an error:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

I'm specifying my data provider name in `Web.config` thus:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
         invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
         description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
         type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory,
               Oracle.DataAccess.Client,
               Version=2.112.2.0,
               Culture=neutral,
               PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Is the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll on the target machine?

Comment: @Kramb `Oracle.DataAccess` is not `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, they are different. Did you install the provider, you can download it from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)

Answer (score 0):

You request `Version=2.112.2.0`, however your compile target is .NET  Framework 4.0 or 4.5

Thus you must also install and use ODP.NET (i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) version 4.112.x.x, otherwise it does not work.

ODP.NET version 1.x / 2.x and 4.x are not compatible to each other. If you have to support all of them you must provide separate binary of your application for each version (unless you do Late-Binding)

Comment: Hi Wernfried Domscheit, thanks for your reply. i re installed oracle client and it is working fine. once again many thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to install the following software:

1. .Net Framework 4.5
2. Oracle Client